# When would a verilog state-machine go wrong?

Tags: verilog, fpga, state-machine

**This is my verilog code:**

```
//state reg
(* syn_encoding = "safe" *)reg [3:0] ns_sig, cs_sig;
//state parameters
localparam 
    sLOW    = 4'b0001,
    sTO_HIGH    = 4'b0010,
    sHIGH   = 4'b0100,
    sTO_LOW = 4'b1000;

always @(posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
    if (!rst_n)
        cs_sig <= sLOW;
    else
        cs_sig <= ns_sig;

always @(*)
begin
    ns_sig = cs_sig;
    case (cs_sig)
        sLOW:
            if (sig == `HIGH)
                ns_sig = sTO_HIGH;
        sTO_HIGH:
            if (valid_HIGH == `ON)
                ns_sig = sHIGH;
            else if (sig == `OFF)
                ns_sig = sLOW;
        sHIGH:
            if (sig == `OFF)
                ns_sig = sTO_LOW;
        sTO_LOW:
            if (valid_LOW == `ON)
                ns_sig = sLOW;
            else if (sig == `ON)
                ns_sig = sHIGH;
        default:
            ns_sig = sLOW;
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (cs_sig == sTO_HIGH)
        cnt_HIGH <= cnt_HIGH + {{(pWIDTH-1){1'b0}}, 1'b1};
    else
        cnt_HIGH <= {(pWIDTH){1'b0}};
end

assign
    valid_HIGH = (cnt_HIGH == pHIGH_DEPTH -1)? `ON:`OFF;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (cs_sig == sTO_LOW)
        cnt_LOW <= cnt_LOW + {{(pWIDTH-1){1'b0}}, 1'b1};
    else
        cnt_LOW <= {(pWIDTH){1'b0}};
end

assign
    valid_LOW = (cnt_LOW == pLOW_DEPTH - 1)?`ON:`OFF;


always @(posedge clk)
begin
    if (cs_sig == sHIGH)
        sig_sf <= `HIGH;
    else if (cs_sig == sLOW)
        sig_sf <= `LOW;
end
```

It is a binary signal filter block aiming to nail the glitches on a physical port and can be used as a delayer at the same time.

It runs good on simulation, but not on board. I ran the code on a Altrea EP2C35 chip and it went wrong every now and then. Normally the `sig_sf` would be `pLOW_DEPTH` (I set it to 200) clks behind input `sig`, but it would be sometimes just 2 clks behind.

I added a signaltap to see what happened, and it turned out that the statemachine went wrong. The valid values on signaltap were: `sLOW, sTO_LOW, sHIGH, s_TO_HIGH`, just as I set. But it went to `4'h1` at some neg-edge of `sig` and it resets to `sLOW`.

But I don't understand why, I am sure that the input wave from a generator is just fine.

So HELP me with this, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Your `always @(*)` creates combinatorial logic based on internal (clocked) signals and your external input.  The external input can change at any time, so sometimes your registered logic in `always @(posedge clk)` blocks will see glitches because the output of your combinatorial logic did not meet the setup and hold times required by the registers in the FPGA.  Before you can do "large scale" de-glitching of your input you need to do single-clk scale de-glitching of your input.  You do that with a *synchronizer*.

See [Understanding Metastability in FPGAs](http://www.altera.com/literature/wp/wp-01082-quartus-ii-metastability.pdf) for a white paper on the subject by Altera.  If you Google synchronizer / metastability you'll find tons of references.

You might be wondering why simulation doesn't show the problem.  This kind of issue is detected by the timing analyzer, but you have to tell it about your signals in the constraints file so it knows what's going on.  There's nothing wrong with your *code*.  The problem is the physical signal `sig`.  If the timing analyzer knew it was in a clock domain unrelated to `clk` it could warn you.

Also, you have found the danger of one-hot encoding in state machines:  Your 4-bit state variables have 4 valid values and 12 invalid "holes" you can fall into, leaving your machine in limbo.

Comment: thanks a lot. A few minutes ago, I changed the _encoding attribute_ to _user_ and encode the states with 2-bit grey code, and the program ran correctly. And according to your answer, I guess I need to add an FF between `sig` and the state-machine, and then it would be all right.